# How to get app config data from a file in s3 bucket before user logged in to the app for a multi-tenant application?

Tags: django, reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, aws-sdk

I am using `s3-bucket` to store app config data for multi tenant application. I need tenant info saved in public file(`.json`) in `s3-bucket` before client is logged in to the application. For example, app config data might be client logo and some custom title/sub-title for each tenant and etc. I am trying to fetch file content based on sub-domain.

So, I need to fetch the client data, while rendering the login component itself. I am using `aws-sdk` tool in client side, but am facing 'missing credentials` error.

I am not getting, How to achieve this??

thanks and regards
SHASHIDHAR N K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Javascript uses the S3 rest API in such a way that it requires a GET request to be authorized. This is because it uses request parameters to override response header values and for these the rest API documentation for GET says:

> Note - You must sign the request, either using an Authorization header or a pre-signed URL, when using these parameters. They cannot be used with an unsigned (anonymous) request.

However, you don't need to use S3 to get a public file, you can make a standard http request using XMLHttpRequest or suchlike.

Comment: Is their any security risks making a file public in s3 bucket??

Comment: As long as it's only publically readable; not writable; and contains no sensitive data, then no.